# Search box for article list in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a Search Box and button that returns all rows that contain what is typed into the box, all cells are string values and there are 350 rows and 6 columns i want to search.

The leftmost column is filled with article names which will become hyperlinks to articles, the next five columns are major keywords from the articles, but I would like the search to look at all rows and columns and then hide or filter the non matching rows.

This approach doesn't seem to be working, am I using InStr incorrectly? Note that cell (2,1) is the search box.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    BeginRow = 6
    EndRow = 350
    BeginCol = 1
    EndCol = 8

    For ColCnt = BeginCol To EndCol
        For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
            If InStr(Cells(RowCnt, ColCnt).Value, Cells(2, 1).Value) = 0 Then
                Cells(RowCnt, ColCnt).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Else
                Cells(RowCnt, ColCnt).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
        Next RowCnt
    Next ColCnt
End Sub
```

Comment: Your macro will loop through but in the end EndCol will define whether given row is hidden or not. I recommend looping through rows and giving a  logical value, say default True, then change it if the columns fit your criteria. At the end of the row's loop hide or unhide in accordance with your logical value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify what "doesn't seem to be working" really means, but if I were to venture a guess I'd say:

You start your search in Col 1. After not finding it in the link text, you move on to Col 2 and find the keyword in `Cell(7,2)` so you make row 7 visible.

Later you're searching Col 3, you get to testing `Cell(7,3)`, don't find the keyword there, so you hide the row. But wait, it was in row 7, so you want it visible!

If that's your problem, I'd recommend switching to a Row then Column search pattern. For each Row, set `found=false` then search your columns, if you find it, set `found=true`.

When you're done searching the columns for that row, set `.EntireRow.Hidden = Found`.

A much quicker way would be

```
dim rng as range

set rng = Worksheet.range(cells(beginCol, BeginRow), Cells(EndCol, EndRow)).Find What:=Cells(2,1)
while not rng = nothing
  'do your FOUND stuff here
  set rng = Worksheet.range(cells(beginCol, BeginRow), Cells(EndCol, EndRow)).Find What:=Cells(2,1)
end while
```

Comment: Thank you!  I can't believe that I overlooked that, you were right, it was basically only searching the last column.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. I'd strongly recommend you use `.Find` instead, though. It will be significantly faster. Set all rows to hidden, then with the results of `.Find` set those rows to visible. May not matter much on a 350x8 block of cells, but it will when you're looking at thousands of rows, and it'll be a good trick to have in the bag.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a similar thing, it finds all matches in the *ertdfgcvb* named range and then creates a dropdown with all matches. Then it places the first matching value in the *Target* cell.

```
Sub listakészítő(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo Err
szoveg = "*" & Target.Value & "*"
x = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("ertdfgcvb"), szoveg) - 1
Dim MyList() As String
ReDim MyList(0 To x)
Dim cella As Range
i = 0
On Error Resume Next

For Each cella In Range("Ertdfgcvb")
    If CStr(cella.Value) Like szoveg Then
    MyList(i) = CStr(cella.Value)
    i = i + 1
    End If
Next cella

On Error GoTo Err

With Target.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
         Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(MyList, ",")
    .ShowError = False
End With

Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target = MyList(0)
Application.EnableEvents = True

Err:
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a [faster horse](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Talk:Henry_Ford), here's what you're looking for:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

BeginRow = 6
EndRow = 350
BeginCol = 1
EndCol = 8

For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow 'in each row
    For ColCnt = BeginCol To EndCol 'check each column
        Matching = False 'for matches
        If InStr(Cells(RowCnt, ColCnt).Value, Cells(2, 1).Value) > 0 Then Matching = True 'identify it
    Next ColCnt
    Cells(RowCnt, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = Matching = False 'and hide the row if none of the rows match, unhide if any of them does
Next RowCnt
End Sub
```

Since it was so easy to create I even made an alternative that doesn't operate with a logic dim:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

BeginRow = 6
EndRow = 350
BeginCol = 1
EndCol = 8
For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
Cells(RowCnt, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
Next
For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow 'in each row
    For ColCnt = BeginCol To EndCol 'check each column
        If InStr(Cells(RowCnt, ColCnt).Value, Cells(2, 1).Value) > 0 Then Cells(RowCnt, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: On your first example the inner For/Next loop will exhibit the same toggling issue the OP had. Each time that loop looks at a new column, if forces `Matching = False`, no matter what it was set to before.  The second example will work, though it will be slow because it has to loop all rows twice.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I had no exmple file to test it on.